# Turn a List of Iterators into an Iterator of Lists in Scala 3

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-3

Ahoy! I am learning Scala and making my way through the book Functional Programming in Scala. I have been playing around and found myself in the situation where I want to be able to turn a List of Iterators into an Iterator of Lists, where I start with an inital `List[T]` and have a function that creates an Iterator of `T => Iterator[T]`. I can map that across the initial list and get a `List[Iterator[T]]`, but I ultimately want to turn that into an `Iterator[List[T]]`.

I am certain that I have not explained that well, so here is an example:

```
def collatz(n: Int): Int =
  n % 2 match
    case 0 => n / 2
    case 1 => 3 * n + 1

def collatzes(n: Int): Iterator[Int] =
  Iterator.iterate(n)(collatz)


@main def main: Unit =
  val inits = List(1, 2)
  val iters = inits.map(collatzes)
  val iter = ???
  // want to turn this list of iterators into an iterator of lists,
  // that gives me a list of the _.next of each iterator on each
  // call of iter.next
```

I'm sure I could easily do what I need with a loop of some kind, but would love to know if there is an idiomatic functional way to do this type transform in Scala 3.

Cheers!

Comment: What should each `List` inside the `Iterator` contain?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez if I have a `List[T]` and function `T => Iterator[T]` then I want to be able to construct an `Iterator[List[T]]`. In the example I gave, the list contains integers.

Comment: In "general" `List[X[_]]` to `X[List[_]]` can be done using what is called `.traverse` in libraries (it's not out of the box). But here your `Iterator` type if you really want to keep it and it's behaviour ("lazyness") is forcing you to have a custom approach.

Comment: You want to "move next" in all your iterators at once and get back the result as a list. But you want all of that to be an Iterator as well. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand correctly what you are asking here ... It sounds  like you want to "transpose" your list, so that you can iterate over all the iterators at once?

Something like this perhaps?

```
Iterator.continually(iters.map(_.next))
```

Comment: That was my understanding as well. It's elegant and concise but not super straightforward to grasp why it works IMHO. @OP: if you ever really use this, please add a comment regarding the magic lazyness happening here for future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

Hoping not to be too simplistic, I would probably just do the following:

```
val iter = iters.iterator.map(_.toList)
```

The `iterator` method is defined on all `Iterable`s, including `List`s, and as you can imagine it returns an `Iterator` of the original collection. The `map` function applies a function to each nested `Iterator`, turning each one in a concrete list. Since the `Iterator` is lazy, the nested `Iterator`s will become a concrete `List` only when you actually use `iter`.

A word of warning: `Iterator`s are great, but you need to handle them with care if you wish to use a purely functional approach, since `Iterator`s are designed to be stateful, resulting in behavior that doesn't lend itself to make function referentially transparent, e.g.:

```
// The iterator needs to be traversed for the size to be known
// but the process of traversing the iterator moves its internal
// cursor to the end, resulting in the first it.size to be == 1
// and the second one to be == 0
val it = Iterator.iterate(0)(_ + 1).takeWhile(_ < 1)
assert(it.size != it.size)
```

For a lazy, memoized, built-in alternative to `Iterator`s you might want to have a look at [`LazyList`s](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/collections-classes.html#aside-the-lazylist) or [`View`s](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/views.html).